# Remove matching documents from the entire mongo db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an API where a user can add, update and delete `cats` - for the sake of the example.

Each `cat` will have references to other `mongodb` collections, lets say `owner` and `vet`.

So when I add a cat, this is what the `mongodb` collections will look like after the program runs once:

```
db.find.cats()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("580"), "name" : "Hi", "username" : "test1111"}

db.find.vet()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("111"), "place" : "World", "username" : "test1111"}

db.find.owner()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("123"), "job" : "Engineer", "username" : "test1111"}
```

When a user deletes a `Cat`, I want all of the three documents across the three collections to be deleted, because they are linked to the cat through the cats username. How can I do this?

I have tried this:

```
router.delete('/test', function (req, res, next) {
  Cats.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
      res.json({success: true});
  });
});
```

However this only deletes the cat from the `Cat` collection as I am searching only for the Id - which behaves like expected. Would I have to perform find and remove for each collection separately?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You do have a option to make a single collection.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously when you fire a findByIDandRemove on cats collection  `Cats.findByIdAndRemove` it is going to delete it from that single collection only and usually that is how you are supposed to write the code.

if you want to delete it from all the three then you need to call `findByIdAndRemove` on the vet and owner collections also.

Comment: Yes I know... thats what I said in the question. So there is no way to search the whole database? And is it possible to do all of that in the same method? If so how?

Comment: you can. for that you need to do the following. once you get a mongo connection create var collection = db.collection('cat'), fire delete statement, var collection = db.collection('vet'), fire delete statement, var collection - db.collection ('owner') fire delete statement.

Comment: So I have to do three separate statements basically?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a listener that maintains the integrity of related collections.

> When Deleting set one additional property `toBeDeleted: true`
>
> Listen to updates on `Cats` table. Looks for some `toBeDeleted: true`
>
> Listening Code performs referential integrity management as you
>      like:
>
> > remove from `Cats`
> >
> > remove from `Vets`
> >
> > remove from `Owners`

Hence collections should not be related. To avoid this overhead you can keep all three as one document. You can always retrieve unique Owners and Vets from that document. Follow the documentation. In general we should try not mongodb in a relational paradigm (although I understand some situations which warrants what you are doing.)

Comment: How would this look like in node js?

Comment: Well if you are using nodeJS amd using mongojs driver then another quick solution is to consider should consider `mongodb-trigger` https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-triggers I believe it works client side and lets you intercept things. The client that deletes ensures the deletion of other collection. Not sure if you want this.